# Balancing Create/Delete Options

Tags: usability, forms

In my admin page for a course registration system, administrators can create courses with attributes like city, school, and course name. Admins also need to manage cities and schools by creating or deleting them. Currently, there's a 'Courses' section on the main page, where admins can view and edit courses and create new ones.

Is it recommended to include a combobox for selecting cities and schools for course creation and management, or should I create separate pages for these tasks? If separate pages are the way to go, what's the best way to navigate to them from the main page? I'm concerned that having a menu like 'Courses,' 'Cities,' and 'Schools,' especially a page just for creating/deleting cities, might seem unusual.

**The form**

[image]

**ComboBox with select / create / delete**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A good way to come up with the information you need to make the decision is to map out the userflow for the course creation vs. course management paths.

So you need to consider what the minimum number of steps is required to create a course (i.e. the number of fields to populate the course 'object'), and whether these can be done in a single step or multiple stages.

Then you need to work out the use cases for managing the courses, because adding, updating and deleting courses can have an effect on other things (like the scheduling or timetable of courses, student records, etc.), and whether all of the steps can be done linearly and whether there are other dependencies.

Once you have worked these things out, and if they are both simple enough to contain in a single page, then you can put them in the same page for convenience. But if you find that there are many rules and validations and use cases that can't be easily contained in a simple and linear flow, then you should consider a separate page to help make it easier for the user.

Of course, you can also make a simple prototype and test it with users to get a feel for how difficult this would be for the users.